# How can I substitute a quote in bash script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, escape-sequences

I have this bash script

```
 #!/bin/bash
 find . -type f > /home/wschrabi/filenames
 while read filename; do
       stripped="$(printf '%s\n' "$filename" | tr -d -C '[[:alnum:]][[:space:]][!\"\#\$\%\&\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\@\[\\\]\^\_`{|}~]')";
       ohne="$(sed -e 's/[\d126-\d255\"*:<>\?\\\|]/_/g' <<<$filename)";
       test "$filename" = "$stripped" || printf "mv '%s' '%s'\n " "${filename//[\']/'\\''}" "${ohne//[\'\"\`]/_}"; 
 done < /home/wschrabi/filenames
```

and at the part `${filename//[\']/'\\''}` I would like to substitute a single quote in the filename. The purpose should be that when I pipe the output in a bash script I would like to rename all filenames automatically. But the single quotes make problems.

Thanks a lot for any advices.
Walter

EDIT:
Here is for completion my chekc NTFS for Filename script.

```
     #!/bin/bash
     #
     # Quote a string, wrapping it in tick marks ('), and escaping any
     # embedded ticks.
     #
     # Inputs:
     #   $1: The string to quote
     #
     # Returns:
     #   (stdout) - The quoted string
     #
     quote() {
         if [ $(echo "$@" | tr -d "\n" | wc -c) -eq 0 ]; then
             echo "''"
         elif [ $(echo "$@" | tr -d "[a-z][A-Z][0-9]:,.=~_/\n-" | wc -c) -gt 0 ]; then
             echo "$@" | sed -e "s/'/\'\"\'\"\'/g" | sed -e "s/^/'/g" -e "s/$/'/g"
         else
             echo "$@"
         fi
     }

     if [ $# -eq 0 ]
       then echo "No arguments supplied: USAGE: checkNTFS_filenames.sh <file_to_check>" 
     fi

     if [ $# -eq 1 ]
     then

     #find . -type f > /home/wschrabi/filenames2
     while read filename; do
           stripped="$(printf '%s\n' "$filename" | tr -d  '\"\*\:\<\>\?\\\|')";
           ohne="$(sed -e 's/[\d126-\d255\"*:<>\?\\\|]/_/g' <<<$filename)";
           if [ "$filename" != "$stripped" ]  ;
           then  printf "mv %s %s\n" "$(quote "$filename")" "$(quote "$stripped")" 
           fi
     done < $1
     fi
```

Comment: I have added another answer, not to detract from virtex's, which is correct, but to point out there shorter, more efficient ways to do this., that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your filenames between tick marks, escaping characters with a backslash won't work. There is another way to do it though.  Here's a quote function I've used in the past that might be useful to you.

```
#
# Quote a string, wrapping it in tick marks ('), and escaping any
# embedded ticks.
#
# Inputs:
#   $1: The string to quote
#
# Returns:
#   (stdout) - The quoted string
#
quote() {
    if [ $(echo "$@" | tr -d "\n" | wc -c) -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "''"
    elif [ $(echo "$@" | tr -d "[a-z][A-Z][0-9]:,.=~_/\n-" | wc -c) -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "$@" | sed -e "s/'/\'\"\'\"\'/g" | sed -e "s/^/'/g" -e "s/$/'/g"
    else
        echo "$@"
    fi
}
```

When you run it you get outputs like these.

```
$ quote abc
abc
$ quote "abc'def"
'abc'"'"'def'
$ quote \"abc\"
'"abc"'
$ quote "abc def"
'abc def'
```

The idea here is that you can replace the final printf in your script with this:

```
printf "mv %s %s\n" "$(quote "$filename")" "$(quote "$ohne")"
```

Using a filename of abc'def with your script with the above change I got this as my output.

```
mv 'abc'"'"'def' abcdef
```

and that successfully renamed the file when executed.

Answer (score 0):

Virtex answer is of course perfectly correct. I would just like to point out that this kind of operation is easier to carry out with *Bash arrays*: just to make it clear, let us assume we wish to strip the initial characters *./* which *find* leaves on the file names in this simple command:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

This can be done as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a mylist
mylist=(`find -maxdepth 1 -type f `)
mylist=(${mylist[@]/\.\//})
echo "${mylist[@]}"
```

[Bash search and replace](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace) works on arrays as one would hope: by modifying the array elements one by one. This can be modified to include your example.

**EDIT**:

> what if I have millions of files?

How about 10 millions?

```
$ time /bin/bash -c 'unset array &&  declare -a array && array=($(seq 1 10000000)) && echo "${array[6]}"; unset array'
7

real    0m11.110s
user    0m10.412s
sys     0m0.724s

$ inxi -C
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-5500U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 4096 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 3000 MHz 1: 2509 MHz 2: 2471 MHz 3: 2631 MHz 4: 2471 MHz
```

Comment: Thanks Marius, but what if I have millions of files? Would there a RAM memory limit for the bash arrays?

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair Pls see my Edit.